# How to upload formData file with express-upload in node js server

Tags: node.js-fs, express-fileupload

I'm attempting to upload a local file to a node js express server.
My local client upload looks like this:

```
const file = await fs.readFileSync(`${desktopDir}/ai2html-output/home-pro-Artboard_1.jpg`);
const title = "Test";

const form = new FormData();

form.append("name", title);
form.append("file", file);

console.log(form);
```

form console log is:

```
dataSize: 0
maxDataSize: 2097152
pauseStreams: true
readable: true
writable: false
_boundary: "--------------------------148357794967581903667353"
_currentStream: null
_insideLoop: false
_overheadLength: 246
_pendingNext: false
_released: false
_streams: (6) ["----------------------------1483577949675819036673…
↵Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"
↵
↵", "Test", ƒ, "----------------------------1483577949675819036673…file"
↵Content-Type: application/octet-stream
↵
↵", Buffer(42595), ƒ]
_valueLength: 42599
```

I then fetch to the server:

```
const response = await fetch('https://example.com/uploads/1234', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
        "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data`,
      },
  body: form });
```

In my express server:

```
    const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
    app.use(fileUpload());

router.post('/uploads/:id', (req, res) => {
  let sampleFile;
  let uploadPath;

  if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
  }

  // The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
  sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;
  uploadPath = __dirname + '/var/www/vhosts/preview.inkto.art/httpdocs/html/' + sampleFile.name;

  // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
  sampleFile.mv(uploadPath, function(err) {
    if (err)
      return res.status(500).send(err);

    res.send('File uploaded!');
  });
})
```

The response from the server says 400  'No files were uploaded' in the request header says:

```
[object FormData] for the payload.
```

Any idea why it's not recognizing the file?  What am I missing?